# Is it possible to load a local file in preload.js when on a website using electron?

Tags: electron

I'm currently trying to make a simple electron app that launches a website (for example:  `mainWindow.loadURL('https://www.google.com')`), then apply a local image as the background.

I've been using links from online, but I'm hoping to be able to access a local image in my preload.js. It doesn't seem I can access my file system in any way if I launch the window with a website. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `fs` module and the `window.postMessage` function

```js
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')

// Listen for a message from the renderer process
ipcMain.on('load-local-image', (event, arg) => {
  // Read the contents of the local file using the fs module
  const fs = require('fs')
  const imageData = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/local/image.jpg')

  // Send the image data back to the renderer process
  event.sender.send('local-image-loaded', imageData)
})


const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

// Send a message to the main process to load the local image
ipcRenderer.send('load-local-image')

// Listen for a response
ipcRenderer.on('local-image-loaded', (event, imageData) => {
  // set the background image
  // document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageData})` with url
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = `${imageData}`
})
```

Read more about the `preload.js`
in the documentation: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-preferences#preload.

Comment: it appears that when I use the code above, it sets the background image to                            (*website URL*)/(*image data*) rather than the image data itself.

Comment: try removing the url() function

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to pass files through now. Turns out the only problem I was having was that my function wasn't waiting on ipcRenderer.on to trigger and setting the backgroundImage to an undefined value. ipcRenderer.sendSync was what I needed.